# Mocking the AWS SDK in Golang?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, mocking, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

I am in a situation where I need to mock elements of the Lambda, API Gateway and S3 SDK packages for unit testing.

I initially thought this wouldn't be such a bad idea but right now having to implement some in-memory data storage and mimic the entire AWS logic for those services seems impossible (or at least really time consuming).

So basically my mock-implementation looks something like this

```
package awsmock

type Lambda struct {
    lambda.Lambda
    data map[string]*LambdaFunction
}

func (svc *Lambda) CreateFunction(...) (...) {
    // mimic the AWS logic but save to svc.data
}

// etc
```

Is there any better way you could think of when it comes to mocking AWS SDK? If there isn't, I could write a library and post it on Github so other can use it and improve it too, but I hope I can manage without reimplementing this.

Comment: Re-implementing the logic with a different data storage, that's not a mock but an alternative implementation. When using mocks you don't have to deal with storage nor logic.

Comment: @mkopriva my package executes lots of API calls via the SDK: `lambda.GetFunction` to check if it exists, then `lambda.ListVersionsByFunction` to check the latest available version, then `lambda.ListAliases` then `lambda.CreateAlias` (if needed) etc. So I still need to mimic the logic in order to return some coherent output, otherwise testing is useless.

Comment: If you want to mimic the logic, that's fine. What I tried to point out in the initial comment is that that's not a mock, if you want to mock the service you're doing it the wrong way, if you want to mimic the logic you're naming it the wrong way.

Comment: Also if you gonna mimic the logic, you may have to consider writing tests for that as well, how else would you prove that the output it returns is correct? that the alternative behaves the same way as the real thing? Because if it doesn't behave the same but all the other tests that depend on the service pass without fail, what would that mean? Will they still pass when they use the real service?

Comment: @mkopriva you're perfectly right. that's why I posted this question here: I thought of these things myself too and it seems like a huge overhead. That's why I am asking for a better idea

Comment: Instead of the in-memory implementation using a real mock would be more practical I think. Define an *interface type* with the lambda methods that your app needs, then have all your types that depend on lambda proper depend on that interface instead, in production set it to the real service, in testing set it to a mock. You don't have to manually write the mock, you can use https://github.com/golang/mock to generate it. And there in the README you can also see how the mock's supposed to be used, how you set expectations and return values.

Comment: @mkopriva I will look into this and come back to you with what I've done! seems like a very clever way! thanks!